# Exporting a Java project from Processing 3 to a Windows Application

Tags: java, processing

I recently wanted to try out the IDE Processing 3. After making a simple program to test the IDE I tryed to export the project. The build failed and after some searching *I came to not conclusion.

```
void setup(){

    size(300,300);

}

void draw(){

    background(0);

}
```

```
Compiling resources
C:\Users\Username\Java\Processing3\processing-3.5.3-install-zip\modes\java\application\launch4j\bin\windres.exe: preprocessing failed.
Generated resource file...

LANGUAGE 0, 1
2 RCDATA BEGIN "1.8.0_74\0" END
18 RCDATA BEGIN "1\0" END
30 RCDATA BEGIN "2\0" END
12 RCDATA BEGIN "-Djna.nosys=true -Djava.library.path=""%EXEDIR%\\lib""\0" END
1 ICON DISCARDABLE "C:\\Users\\Username\\Java\\Processing3\\processing-3.5.3-install-zip\\modes\\java\\application\\sketch.ico"
21 RCDATA BEGIN "http://java.com/download\0" END
20 RCDATA BEGIN "32\0" END
101 RCDATA BEGIN "An error occurred while starting the application.\0" END
102 RCDATA BEGIN "This application was configured to use a bundled Java Runtime Environment but the runtime is missing or corrupted.\0" END
103 RCDATA BEGIN "This application requires a Java Runtime Environment\0" END
104 RCDATA BEGIN "The registry refers to a nonexistent Java Runtime Environment installation or the runtime is corrupted.\0" END
15 RCDATA BEGIN "TestOne\0" END
16 RCDATA BEGIN "lib\\TestOne.jar;lib\\core.jar;lib\\jogl-all.jar;lib\\gluegen-rt.jar;lib\\jogl-all-natives-windows-i586.jar;lib\\gluegen-rt-natives-windows-i586.jar\0" END

windows:


BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\Username\Java\Processing3\Tests\TestOne\application.windows32\launch4j-build.xml:5: net.sf.launch4j.BuilderException: net.sf.launch4j.ExecException: Exec failed (1): C:\Users\Username\Java\Processing3\processing-3.5.3-install-zip\modes\java\application\launch4j\bin\windres.exe --preprocessor=type -J rc -O coff -F pe-i386 C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\launch4j8828112920620076117rc C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\launch4j3878491496617260507o
    at net.sf.launch4j.Builder.build(Builder.java:149)
    at net.sf.launch4j.ant.Launch4jTask.execute(Launch4jTask.java:111)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at processing.mode.java.JavaBuild.buildWindowsLauncher(JavaBuild.java:1231)
    at processing.mode.java.JavaBuild.exportApplication(JavaBuild.java:1102)
    at processing.mode.java.JavaBuild.exportApplication(JavaBuild.java:713)
    at processing.mode.java.JavaMode.handleExportApplication(JavaMode.java:239)
    at processing.mode.java.JavaEditor.exportApplicationPrompt(JavaEditor.java:945)
    at processing.mode.java.JavaEditor.handleExportApplication(JavaEditor.java:575)
    at processing.mode.java.JavaEditor$3.actionPerformed(JavaEditor.java:198)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:842)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:886)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: net.sf.launch4j.ExecException: Exec failed (1): C:\Users\Username\Java\Processing3\processing-3.5.3-install-zip\modes\java\application\launch4j\bin\windres.exe --preprocessor=type -J rc -O coff -F pe-i386 C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\launch4j8828112920620076117rc C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\launch4j3878491496617260507o
    at net.sf.launch4j.Util.exec(Util.java:156)
    at net.sf.launch4j.Cmd.exec(Builder.java:215)
    at net.sf.launch4j.Builder.build(Builder.java:100)
    ... 57 more

Total time: 0 seconds
+
```

After trying to export the above code into an Application I got that error in the console. In the folder where the App was supposed to be created there was no .exe

Comment: Are you trying to bundle Java with your application?

Comment: @KevinWorkman The computer I want to run the executable file on already has Java installed, so I will try without Java being bundled.

Comment: @KevinWorkman No change in results unfortunately. Maybe i'm not exporting it correctly? https://pasteboard.co/Iq1R094.png